# What does "either A or B" mean precisely, and how can I prove it?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I am in an argument about the phrase "either A or B". I believe it is necessarily exclusive, meaning it refers the possibilities of A or B **but not both**.

But, after scouring the internet, I can't find a reliable source to back me up. How could I definitively determine whether I am right or not?

(I found [this](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/either-or) by the way, but it refers to "either-or" and not the longer phrase "either [one thing] or [another thing]")

Comment: It means many things.  To a mathematician you'd need to specify "inclusive OR" or "exclusive OR" to be sufficiently precise.

Comment: There may be natural languages that enforce the distinction between inclusive and exclusive "or", but English definitely isn't one of them.